# Accessing system dbus twice gives segmentation fault

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, race-condition, glib, dbus

Dbus gives me some headache. Namely calling SystemBus() twice, will give me segmentation fault in most of the times. Sometimes it gives some other random errors so I guess this is a race condition.

```
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop
from time import sleep
import threading
import dbus, gobject


# Monitor usb on a separate thread
def monitor_usb():
    DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
    dbus.SystemBus()                      # Probably source of error
    gobject.threads_init()
    gobject.MainLoop().run()
thread=threading.Thread(target=monitor_usb)
thread.daemon=True
thread.start()


# Calling this while monitor_usb is running
# will cause segmentation fault
dbus.SystemBus()
sleep(10)
```

Is there a way to solve this?